# SQLite two values unique in combination

Tags: sql, sqlite, unique

I have a SQLite database with the following tables:
There is a Persons table (ID, name,...) and a Pets table (ID, name, owner,...), where owner is a foreign key that refers to a row of Persons. 
A person can have as many pets as they want, but each pet must have an individual name.

The problem is that the name must be unique only for the same owner, a name can occur more than once in the Pets table, but only once per ID of the person stored in the owners column.
Therefore, the name column cannot be unique, but owner and name together should be.

How can this be achieved in SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

You simply want a unique constraint or index:

```
create unique index unq_pets_owner_name on pets(owner, name);
```